# Selenium webdriver is unable to locate element in chrome headless mode

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium

I wrote the following script to practice Selenium browser automation. It accesses Steam's website and changes your Steam username. It works perfectly if run without Chrome's headless mode but fails to locate the very first element if started with `options.addArguments("headless")`. The code:

```java
@Test
public void steamPowered() throws IOException {

    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Driver\\chromedriver.exe");

    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.addArguments("--user-data-dir=C://Users/Evan/Downloads/Profile8Aug17");
    options.addArguments("headless");
    options.addArguments("window-size=1200x600");

    ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);

    driver.navigate().to("https://store.steampowered.com/");

    WebElement element = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10))
            .until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("account_pulldown")));
    element.click();

    element = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10))
            .until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"account_dropdown\"]/div/a[4]")));
    element.click();

    element = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10))
            .until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath
            ("/html/body/div[1]/div[7]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[3]/div[2]/a/span")));
    element.click();

    element = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10))
            .until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("personaName")));
    element.clear();
    element.sendKeys(scramble(USERNAME));

    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[text()='Save Changes']")).click();

    driver.quit();
}
```

}

The intellij printout when it crashes:

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate 
element: {"method":"id","selector":"account_pulldown"}
  (Session info: headless chrome=60.0.3112.90)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.31.488763 
(092de99f48a300323ecf8c2a4e2e7cab51de5ba8),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 
x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
```

This is confusing because the following code works perfectly (copy pasted from https://medium.com/@eliasnogueira/running-selenium-tests-with-chrome-headless-5edd624efb92)

```java
@Test
public void testExecution() throws IOException {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Driver\\chromedriver.exe");

    // Add options to Google Chrome. The window-size is important for responsive sites
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.addArguments("--user-data-dir=C://Users/Evan/Downloads/Profile8Aug17");
    options.addArguments("headless");
    options.addArguments("window-size=1200x600");

    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
    driver.get("http://seleniumhq.org");

    // a guarantee that the test was really executed
    assertTrue(driver.findElement(By.id("q")).isDisplayed());

    driver.quit();
}
```

So what am I missing here? I fail to see any serious difference between the two. What's stopping my script from locating page elements in headless mode?

Comment: Get the PageSource in headless mode and see if something is wrong

Comment: What is `"--user-data-dir=C://Users/Evan/Downloads/Profile8Aug17"` all about? Are you trying to load a Chrome Profile?

Comment: @DebanjanB That's right. That's the (possibly naive) solution to a problem I had. The chrome instance fails to navigate when using my default profile. A chrome window will open, but then freezes and closes after a minute or so and intellij throws the error `org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: crashed`. So I pointed the driver to an arbitrary location like /Downloads/ instead, where it created a new profile that I've been using without issue until I tried headless mode.

Comment: @TarunLalwani The PageSource is 1910 lines long and contains 24 instances of keyword "account" when run without headless mode, but when run with --headless the PageSource is only 1729 lines long and contains 3 instances of "account". So I think you're on to something. However nothing I've found online about chrome headless has said anything about the PageSource being changed in headless mode, so I'm not sure what's happening here.

Comment: @evanyoho, The issue is headless is a very new feature, and this may have small change in few of the JS behavior which a framework in your JS might be using. So I expect such things to be there till the headless feature matures in chrome. But you will need to find the source of what is causing the HTML to be different

Comment: @TarunLalwani I'll look into it and see what I can find. Thank you for the help. I really appreciate it.

Comment: `The chrome instance fails to navigate when using my default profile` is pretty much correct as our default profile may contain several extensions and add-ons which `chromedriver` fails to load. You can see this [**Discussion**](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=1801&can=1&q=reporter%3Adebanjan.selenium%40gmail.com&colspec=ID%20Status%20Pri%20Owner%20Summary)

Answer (score 0):

try changing screen size to "1920x1080" sometimes you do find trouble when screen size is inappropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try with the belwo settings:

```
options.addArguments("window-size=1400,800");
options.addArguments("headless");
```

Answer (score -1):

In order to use headless chrome using ChromeOptions in java you are supposed to use `--headless`, you may just replace:

```
options.addArguments("headless");
```

with:

```
options.addArguments("--headless");
```

Comment: This doesn't help, when chrome window is open everything works perfectly, when I add .addArguments("--headless") or .setHeadless(true) I get:
"org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element"

Comment: so how to counter this problem?